# RenderObjectElement.insertChildRenderObject() is deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart

Rather than overriding insertChildRenderObject() in your RenderObjectElement subclass, override insertRenderObjectChild() instead, and DON'T call super.insertRenderObjectChild(). If you're implementing a new RenderObjectElement, you should override/implement insertRenderObjectChild(), moveRenderObjectChild(), and removeRenderObjectChild().

```
Stacktrace ::

The relevant error-causing widget was:
HomeWidget HomeWidget:file:///Users/kameshmarellapudi/development/dizest_flutter/lib/pages/landing_page.dart:28:5
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2 Element.rebuild. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:14)
#3 Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4609:6)
#4 BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:19)
#5 WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#6 RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)
#7 SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
#8 SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9)
#9 SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1015:5)
#10 _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
#11 PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
#12 _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)

The following assertion was thrown while rebuilding dirty elements:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4606 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
```

Flutter Version ::

• Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at /Users/kameshmarellapudi/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 135454af32 (6 weeks ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
• Engine revision 3316dd8728
• Dart version 2.18.6
• DevTools version 2.15.0
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/kameshmarellapudi/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
• Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.3.1)
• IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
• Flutter plugin version 71.3.6
• Dart plugin version 223.8214.16

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone 14 Pro (mobile) • D9D3DA56-1621-44B1-B686-F4AFCD38013D • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop) • macos • darwin-x64 • macOS 12.6.2 21G320 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.87

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

Answer..